# Programmatically Synchronize two databases with C#

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, synchronization

I need to update existing data or insert new data from client database say `DB1` into central database say `DB2` both holding same schema and both databases reside in same machine.
 The updates are not biderectional. I just want changes to be reflected from client(`DB1`) to server(`DB2`).
The client database(`DB1`) is nothing but the backup database(Full database backup consisting of mdf and ldf files) of `DB2`.The backup database(`DB1`) already has the modified data when synchronize.
**So how do i do programatically using C# .NET?Can you give any example code?**
I googled about it and saw Microsoft Syn Framework but I don't know how to use it programmatically in C#.
Can you help me with sample code,please?
Sorry for my English.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use SQL Server's built-in replication mechanism?

Comment: Can I use  SQL Server's built-in replication mechanism with C#? Can you give me some sample codes or links ,please? @Roy Dictus Thanks.

Comment: @nnnn Yes you can 'activate' the synchronizing in C# AFAIK.

Comment: @Maarten I am now googling about u said, but I still want an answer from u. Thanks.

Comment: @nnnn I wasn't really clear on re-read. Yes you can synchronize two database by setting up SQL Server's build-in replication mechanism, and activating it at the start of the button. I'll look up some code for the button event handler, the setting up of the replication you'll have to do yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use database mirror concept below i mentioned steps to acheive mirroring  below are the steps

```
Step 1: Create encryption key, certificate and end-points on Principal Instance

/* Execute this against the Principal Instance */
USE MASTER
GO
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password!'
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_PRIN_cert
    WITH SUBJECT = 'HOST_PRIN certificate',
    START_DATE = '01/07/2009'
GO
CREATE ENDPOINT End_Mirroring
    STATE = STARTED
    AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 5022, LISTENER_IP = ALL)
    FOR DATABASE_MIRRORING
    (
        AUTHENTICATION = CERTIFICATE HOST_PRIN_cert,
        ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED ALGORITHM RC4,
        ROLE = ALL
    )
GO
BACKUP CERTIFICATE HOST_PRIN_cert
    TO FILE = 'D:\certificate\HOST_PRIN_cert.cer'
GO

Step 2: Create encryption key, certificate and end-points on Mirror Instance

/* Execute this against the Mirror Instance */
USE master
GO
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password!'
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_MIRR_cert
    WITH SUBJECT = 'HOST_MIRR certificate',
    START_DATE = '01/07/2009'
GO
CREATE ENDPOINT End_Mirroring
    STATE = STARTED
    AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 5023, LISTENER_IP = ALL)
    FOR DATABASE_MIRRORING
    (
        AUTHENTICATION = CERTIFICATE HOST_MIRR_cert,
        ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED ALGORITHM RC4,
        ROLE = ALL
    )
GO
BACKUP CERTIFICATE HOST_MIRR_cert 
    TO FILE = 'D:\certificate\HOST_MIRR_cert.cer';
GO

Step 3: Create login, user and associate certificate with user on Principal Instance

/* 
*  Execute this against the Principal Instance. The HOST_MIRR_cert.cer
*  needs to be copied on the Principal Server.
*/
USE MASTER
GO
/*
*  We are creating a SQL Login here. For Windows logins,
*  use the Grant Login instead of Create Login
*/
CREATE LOGIN HOST_MIRR_login WITH PASSWORD = 'Password!'
GO
CREATE USER HOST_MIRR_user FOR LOGIN HOST_MIRR_login
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_MIRR_cert
    AUTHORIZATION HOST_MIRR_user
    FROM FILE = 'D:\certificate\HOST_MIRR_cert.cer'
GO
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::End_Mirroring TO [HOST_MIRR_login]
GO


Step 4: Create login, user and associate certificate with user on Mirror Instance

/* 
*  Execute this against the Mirror Instance. The HOST_PRIN_cert.cer
*  needs to be copied on the Mirror Server.
*/
USE MASTER
GO
/*
*  We are creating a SQL Login here. For Windows logins, 
*  use the Grant Login instead of Create Login
*/
CREATE LOGIN HOST_PRIN_login WITH PASSWORD = 'Password!'
GO
CREATE USER HOST_PRIN_user FOR LOGIN HOST_PRIN_login
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_PRIN_cert
    AUTHORIZATION HOST_PRIN_user
    FROM FILE = 'D:\certificate\HOST_PRIN_cert.cer'
    GO
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::End_Mirroring TO [HOST_PRIN_login]
GO

Step 5: Create encryption key, certificate and end-points on Witness Instance

/* Execute this against the Witness Instance */
USE MASTER
GO
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password!'
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_WITT_cert
    WITH SUBJECT = 'HOST_WITT certificate',
    START_DATE = '01/07/2009'
GO
CREATE ENDPOINT End_Mirroring
    STATE = STARTED
    AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 5024, LISTENER_IP = ALL)
    FOR DATABASE_MIRRORING
    (
        AUTHENTICATION = CERTIFICATE HOST_WITT_cert,
        ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED ALGORITHM RC4,
        ROLE = Witness
    )
GO
BACKUP CERTIFICATE HOST_WITT_cert
    TO FILE = 'D:\certificate\HOST_WITT_cert.cer'
GO

Step 6: Create login, user and associate certificate with user on Principal Instance

/*
*  Execute this against the Principal Instance. The HOST_WITT_cert.cer
*  needs to be copied on the Principal Server.
*/
USE MASTER
GO
/*
*  We are creating a SQL Login here. For Windows logins,
*  use the Grant Login instead of Create Login
*/
CREATE LOGIN HOST_WITT_login WITH PASSWORD = 'Password!'
GO
CREATE USER HOST_WITT_user FOR LOGIN HOST_WITT_login
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_WITT_cert
    AUTHORIZATION HOST_WITT_user
    FROM FILE = 'D:\certificate\HOST_WITT_cert.cer'
GO
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::End_Mirroring TO [HOST_WITT_login]
GO

Step 7: Create login, user and associate certificate with user on Mirror Instance

/*
*  Execute this against the Mirror Instance. The HOST_WITT_cert.cer
*  needs to be copied on the Mirror Server.
*/
USE MASTER
GO
/*
*  We are creating a SQL Login here. For Windows logins,
*  use the Grant Login instead of Create Login
*/
CREATE LOGIN HOST_WITT_login WITH PASSWORD = 'Password!'
GO
CREATE USER HOST_WITT_user FOR LOGIN HOST_WITT_login
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_WITT_cert
    AUTHORIZATION HOST_WITT_user
    FROM FILE = 'D:\certificate\HOST_WITT_cert.cer'
GO
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::End_Mirroring TO [HOST_WITT_login]
GO

Step 8: Create login, user and associate certificate with user on Witness Instance

/*
*  Execute this against the Witness Instance. The HOST_PRIN_cert.cer
*  and HOST_MIRR_cert.cer needs to be copied on the Witness Server.
*/
USE MASTER
GO
/*
*  We are creating a SQL Login here. For Windows logins,
*  use the Grant Login instead of Create Login
*/
CREATE LOGIN HOST_PRIN_login WITH PASSWORD = 'Password!'
GO
CREATE USER HOST_PRIN_user FOR LOGIN HOST_PRIN_login
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_PRIN_cert
    AUTHORIZATION HOST_PRIN_user
    FROM FILE = 'D:\certificate\HOST_PRIN_cert.cer'
GO
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::End_Mirroring TO [HOST_PRIN_login]
GO
/*
*  We are creating a SQL Login here. For Windows logins,
*  use the Grant Login instead of Create Login
*/
CREATE LOGIN HOST_MIRR_login WITH PASSWORD = 'Password!'
GO
CREATE USER HOST_MIRR_user FOR LOGIN HOST_MIRR_login
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE HOST_MIRR_cert
AUTHORIZATION HOST_MIRR_user
FROM FILE = 'D:\certificate\HOST_MIRR_cert.cer'
GO
GRANT CONNECT ON ENDPOINT::End_Mirroring TO [HOST_MIRR_login]
GO

Step 9: Create the Mirrored Database on the Mirror Server using backups from the Principal Server

/*
*  Execute this against the Principal Instance.
*/
USE MASTER
GO
BACKUP DATABASE MirrorDB
    TO DISK = 'D:\Backups\MirrorDB_FullBackup.bak'
GO
BACKUP LOG MirrorDB
    TO DISK = 'D:\Backups\MirrorDB_LogBackup.trn'
GO
/*
*  Copy MirrorDB_FullBackup.bak and MirrorDB_LogBackup.trn to the
*  Mirror Server.
*  Execute this against the Mirror Instance.
*/
USE MASTER
GO
RESTORE DATABASE MirrorDB
    FROM DISK = 'D:\Backups\MirrorDB_FullBackup.bak'
    WITH NORECOVERY
GO
RESTORE LOG MirrorDB
    FROM DISK = 'D:\Backups\MirrorDB_LogBackup.trn'
    WITH NORECOVERY
GO

Step 10: Setup Mirroring

/*
*  Execute this against the Mirror Instance.
*/
ALTER DATABASE MirrorDB
    SET PARTNER = 'TCP://<<your principal server name here>>:5022'
GO
/*
*  Execute this against the Principal Instance.
*/
ALTER DATABASE MirrorDB
    SET PARTNER = 'TCP://<<your mirror server name here>>:5023'
GO
ALTER DATABASE MirrorDB
    SET WITNESS = 'TCP://<<your witness server name here>>:5024'
GO

At this point your Database Mirroring should be up and running. You can use the Database Mirroring Monitor to verify the setup as well as to monitor the Synchronization status.
```

use below link understand clearly
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suhde/archive/2009/07/13/step-by-step-guide-to-configure-database-mirroring-between-sql-server-instances-in-a-workgroup.aspx

Comment: An little explanation what all this SQL does would be nice.

Comment: i have given link please follow the link u will understanding better

Comment: i suggest you dont do programatically

Comment: But, my system needs it by one button click in UI.

Comment: On every transaction database has to make mirroring through c#

Comment: @ramsTecH - you serious about that? mirror for every transaction?

Answer (score 0):

this should show you how to do this in Sync Framework: [Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700.aspx)

but am not entirely convince why you have to get this done programmatically or by clicking a button.

depending on how much latency/delay you can afford to get the change effected on the other database and what you need it for, you can look at other options like mirroring, replication, triggers, etc...